# Debian 11 is slow and crash multiple times compared to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: debian, ubuntu, intel, lag

I changed my distribution from Ubuntu 22.04 to Debian 11 because it was a complete mess but it was fast, I think it's because Ubuntu uses proprietary drivers for my Intel HD Graphics.

Switching back to Debian 11, everything is working fine but my laptop can't handle multiple tabs or multiple open software windows at a time, it freezes and I have to shut it down manually...

My question is : how can I install the non-free drivers for my Intel HD Graphics ? I don't seem to find any tutorial or articles about that, there's only the integrated kernel driver mentioned in the Debian Wiki...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proprietary drivers in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476715/proprietary-drivers-in-debian)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did install a proprietary driver for my wifi to work but I can't find any proprietary driver for my Intel HD graphics chipset :/